# Use socket from C# in C++

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, pinvoke

I am trying to port my server code from Linux to Windows, so I thought that easiest way would be to write a wrapper in C#.

Basically, what I would C# would do is:

1. C# loads `Server.dll` written entirely in C++ containing functions:

   - `InsertClient(sockId)`
   - `DisconnectClient(sockId)`
   - `ProcessResponse(sockId,len,buffer)`
2. C# creates basic server bound to port N on TCP.
3. When C# server accepts new client and gets Socket struct as return, it must call DLL function `InsertClient(sockId)`
4. When C# server receives some data from the client, it sends it again to DLL function `ProcessResponse(sockId,len,data)`
5. While data are processed all the time in Server.dll and some event happens, Server.dll would send response back to client using the only available function in C++ for sending data: `send(sockId,buffer,len,flags)`

But here it comes to the problem, at point 5, I need to already use socket ID, because without it I can't use `send(...)` , so what I could do is:

- `Server.dll` would invoke call back to main C# application to some somehow exported function, like `SendPacket` containing pointer to Socket struct, which I absolutely don't know if it's possible without using thousands of other framework go arounds.
- In C# I would somehow get to the Socket ID from Socket struct, and send it to C++, so C++ can use it for simple `send(...)`

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: [Calling Native Functions from Managed Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235282.aspx)

Comment: You might want to take a look at p/invoke and C++/CLI.

Comment: What does it change? How do I call native "send" of Ws2 from C# or C++/CLI, when I can't get to yet first param - socket ID from Socket struct returned at Accept?

Comment: What parts need porting, and what kinds of abstraction are you trying to hide behind? The first sentence of your question really needs some more depth, I think (porting from Linux to Windows by wrapping C++ DLL in C# sounds really weird :D)

Comment: I know it sounds really weird, but for sure less complicated than rewriting whole server only because Windows supports I/O Completion ports, so I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: *"How do I call native "send" of Ws2 from C# or C++/CLI"* - With C++/CLI that's easy: Just call it. C++/CLI allows you to write mixed-mode assemblies, that can call native or managed code, while exposing a managed interface, consumable from other .NET languages. Not using C++/CLI when interfacing between native and managed code is a crime.